# Populate drop down fields according to other fields in Drupal 7

Tags: entities

Let's say I have a content type car with content fields brand and model. Now I want to populate the field model according to the value of brand that the user will select. So for example if have:

- BMW

  - series 1
  - series 3
- mercedes

  - a class
  - b class

So if a user chooses BMW as a brand the model field should be populated with series 1 and series 3.

Answer (score 1):

May be [hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select/) is what you are looking for.

Use one taxonomy field with hierarchy to store brands and models. hierarchical_select module will create nice widget for choosing them.

Comment: This was my first idea but this module is unsupported and doesn't work for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by following this tutorial. It works also in webform 4.x, http://www.ishwor.info/dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-drupal-7-webform-3x

Answer (score 0):

I used recently https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_option_limit , is good, easy and nice but can be a pain in the ass if you try to change forms from code later on.